# How to not overwrite on previous text in <p>?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p id='text'>
        hello
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i not overwrite on the previous text

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = " User";
```

when i use innerHTML it just write " User" but i want to make it "hello User" is there any way

Comment: Can you try this document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += " User"; 
I am not sure if it will work in java script but you can try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just concatenate like this :

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += " User";
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p id='text'>
        hello
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much i didn't know it existed.

Comment: No problem, basically here instead of overwriting the content of innerHTML you just add something new at the end of what's already existing

Comment: yeah coming on from cpp its little confusing and i thought innerHTML just replaces the content.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use jQuery to do that.

```js
 $("#text").append(" Appended text.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p id='text'>
        hello
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```